# 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000 Error in Loading DLL Library in C++ Console Application

Tags: c++, dll

I want to load the DLL library in C++ windows console application but I faced to bellow error:

[Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in Token_DLL_Test_1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRO9D.png)

The DLL function definition is:

- **Return** Data Type: uint8_t
- **Argument** 1 Data Type: uint8_t* - Act as String
- **Argument** 2 Data Type: uint8_t - Act as Int
- **Argument** 3 Data Type: uint8_t* - Act as String
- **Argument** 4 Data Type: uint8_t - Act as Int
  And my C++ code is like bellow:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Windows.h>
    
    typedef uint8_t(*FNPTR)(uint8_t*, uint8_t, uint8_t*, uint8_t);
    int main()
    {   
        HINSTANCE hInst = LoadLibrary(L"DLL.dll");
        if (!hInst) {
            std::cout << "\nCould Not Load Library";
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "\nLibrary Loaded Successfully";
        }
        FNPTR fn = (FNPTR)GetProcAddress(hInst, "MasterLogin");
        if (!fn) {
            std::cout << "\nFaliled To Load MasterLogin Function";
            return 0;
        }
        uint8_t name[5];
        uint8_t nameLen = 5;
        memmove(name, "Admin", 5);
        uint8_t pass[6];
        memmove(pass, "123456", 6);
        uint8_t passLen = 6;
        uint8_t res = fn(name, nameLen, pass, passLen);
        std::cout << res;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You aren't allowing for nul-terminators in your strings. `"Admin"` is a **six** character literal. But that may not be the cause of your problem. Without seeing the code for the DLL, it's hard to say.

Comment: @AdrianMole But he copied only 5 chars of it and passed the length. So it should be ok in case the MasterLogin does not treat the parameter as nul-terminated string

Comment: I don't have the DLL source code, I only know the definition of the DLL function.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky Which is why I added *But that may not be the cause of your problem.*

Comment: @HojatSajadinia Can you at least show us the *actual* definition of the function? As in any provided documentation - or what language it is written in. There may be a calling convention conflict.

Comment: uint8_t MasterLogin (uint8_t[] name, uint8_t nameLen, uint8_t[] pass, uint8_t passLen);
this function is used for passing username and password to login into some device. I think it's written in C/C++.

Comment: Do you have some documentation for the function? Or some header file that the *.dll* came with? Which line triggered the crash?